# What is the best way to provide downloadable / uploadable forms?

Tags: web, forms

I need to allow some of my users to design and upload blank forms, to be downloaded, completed, and uploaded by other users.  It would be nice if I could verify the completeness of the uploaded forms, but it is not absolutely necessary.  The respondents are motivated to complete the forms, but it would be nice if I could warn them when one is incomplete.  If I can't verify the content, I would at least like to verify that the uploaded form is the correct form.  I do not intend to implement a form designer.

Can anyone recommend a technology that would facilitate this?  Currently my code doesn't need to understand the forms at all; I am merely passing the data through as a service for the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have previously done some development for the Federal Australian Government.

The Australian Government in conjunction with Adobe created an application called smart forms.  They're effectively web enabled PDF forms which could be downloaded to clients PCS and then filled in offline and submitted later online.

[Adobe LiveCycle](http://www.adobe.com/au/products/livecycle.html)

Adobe LiveCycle is not free however, and there may be licensing costs (I don't recall the particulars).

The Australian Government is successfully using these smart forms in most of their departments.

Comment: link is busted .

Comment: Updated the link to instead point to the Adobe Livecycle website instead of MyGov website explaining how they use their smart forms.